# getStrLn in ZIO working with flatMap but not inside for comprehension

Tags: scala, functional-programming, effects, side-effects, zio

```
val askNameFlatMap: ZIO[Console, IOException, Unit] = putStrLn("What is your Name? ") *>
    getStrLn.flatMap(name => putStrLn(s"Hello $name"))

val askNameFor: ZIO[Console, IOException, Unit] = {
    val getName: ZIO[Console, IOException, String] = getStrLn
    for {
      _ <- putStrLn("What is your Name? ")
      name: String <- getName
      _ <- putStrLn(s"Hello $name")
    } yield ()
  }
```

The version using flatMap is successfully working but when I try to run the for comprehension version then I am getting this error

**Pattern guards are only supported when the error type is a supertype of NoSuchElementException. However, your effect has java.io.IOException for the error type.
name: String <- getName**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove type ascription from your name argument. Type ascription has special meaning in for comprehensions. By saying

```
  for
    name: String <- getStrLn
```

it translates to is something like `getStrLn.withFilter(_.isInstanceOf[String])`

`withFilter` is provided by ZIO implicit but only if Error channel allows to signal about missing elements. Basically your `E` should be supertype of `NoSuchElementException`, i.e. `Exception` or `Throwable`. You have `IOException` and that's why it's not resolving properly.